# Azure change retention time for manual made backup

Tags: azure, server, backup

I have made a manual backup of an azure VM today, which should have been kept only for today. But now I am in the situation where it's needed for more than one day. Now while making the Backup I was asked for a retention time which I didnt change so it was set to 12.11.2019 which is either today ad 00:00 or tomorrow at 00:00 depends on Microsoft. I would like to change the retention time now and keep this backup for longer.

The Policies which can be set in azure seem only to be for backups which were mad by the retention policy.

Answer (score 0):

Your backup will be connected to the Default Policy if you have not connected it to something else.

Therefore, you should be able to change the retention of your backup by editing the default policy.